# Javascript Code returning first array element instead of whole array

Tags: javascript, zapier

I'm using Zapiers JS Code action to request some data from an external API and format it for a Google Sheet.

For some reason, the action is just returning the first array element instead of the whole array with all the objects?

Here's my code:

```
const headers = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': ...
  }
};
const res = await fetch(
  'https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/portfolios/.../items',
  headers
);

const json = await res.json();
let formattedResponse = await Promise.all(json.data.map(async (entry, i) => {
  let projectRequest = await fetch(
    `https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/${entry.gid}`,
    headers
  );
  let projectRes = await projectRequest.json();
  let projObj = {};
  if (projectRes.data.current_status) {
    projObj.author = projectRes.data.current_status.author.name;
    projObj.color = projectRes.data.current_status.color;
    projObj.date = projectRes.data.current_status.created_at;
    projObj.text = projectRes.data.current_status.text;
    projObj.title = projectRes.data.current_status.title;
  };
  console.warn('a', i, projObj);
  return projObj;
}));

console.warn('b', formattedResponse);

return formattedResponse;
```

When tested and reviewed within Zapier, the console messages

```
author: Aaron Wallis
color: blue
date :2021-07-28T10:47:18.074Z
text
Summary
good progress
What we've accomplished
asd
What's blocked
sdf
Next steps
dfg
title: Status Update - 28 Jul
id: ...
runtime_meta:
  memory_used_mb: 76
  duration_ms: 2309
  logs:
    1: WARN a 3 {}
    2: WARN a 1 { author: 'Aaron Wallis', color: 'green', date: '2021-07-28T10:50:15.699Z', text: '...', title: 'qweqwe' }
    3: WARN a 2 {}
    4: WARN a 0 { author: 'Aaron Wallis', color: 'blue', date: '2021-07-28T10:47:18.074Z', text: '...', title: 'Status Update - 28 Jul' }
    5: WARN b [ { author: 'Aaron Wallis', color: 'blue', date: '2021-07-28T10:47:18.074Z', text: '...', title: 'Status Update - 28 Jul' }, { author: 'Aaron Wallis', color: 'green', date: '2021-07-28T10:50:15.699Z', text: '...', title: 'qweqwe' }, {}, {} ]
  async: true
```

You can see that the logs have produced the right output, but the return of `formattedResponse` only contains the first array entry?

I've not used the Code action in Zapier before, so not sure if there's any specific code required to have the full array return?

Edit: Here is a screenshot of the Zapier Zap:
[image]

Comment: `logs: 5: WARN b` is followed by an array of four objects though?

Comment: perhaps it's the way you're calling and using the return value that is at fault, since clearly this code will return the full array - or perhaps, if this is some function that is called by some library, perhaps you need to return in a different format, i.e. `return [formattedResponse]` - best I can come up with without know the specifics of how this function is being used

Comment: am I missing something or "b" contains all 4 items in the array...the only difference is index 0 and 1 have data, while 2 and 3 are empty objects instead of 0  and 1 with data, and 2 and 3 without in the "a" output

Comment: @Bravo: yeah maybe - the code seems to be fine, so it's likely a Zapier thing. Hoping for a Zapier guru to step up :D

Comment: so, you don't call your function directly anywhere?

Comment: @ChrisG and @vanowm, yes, `WARN b` contains all the data required, but Zapier is only (for some reason I don't understand) returning the first element?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of how the code is called.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> For some reason, the action is just returning the first array element instead of the whole array

I suspect it's just that you're not finding the other objects. It can be confusing how they're returning your output, but [their instructions say](https://zapier.com/help/create/code-webhooks/use-javascript-code-in-zaps#output-data-from-code-steps) that if you return the full array, as you're doing:

> If the output is an array of objects, subsequent steps will run multiple times, once for each object in the array.

So if you look inside your next step -- when accessing the output from the code action, there's likely more than one element available, but it may not show up the way you expect (see the screenshots from the instructions to give you an idea).

Depending on your next steps, it might help to change your output to the second suggested format (where you return the elements as line items rather than an array) to see whether this returns something more like what you expect.

```
{"line_items": formattedResponse}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to this party, but another answer is on the right track:

> If the output is an array of objects, subsequent steps will run multiple times, once for each object in the array.

During zap setup, the editor will show only the first item returned. Once the zap runs for real, it will "fan out":

```py
trigger #=> returns [A, B, C, D, E]
# Next action(s) runs 5 times
Action(A)
Action(B)
Action(C)
Action(D)
Action(E)
```

So if your action is "add row to google sheet", then it'll run 5 times and add your 5 rows. It's just confusing because it *doesn't* do that during Zap setup, only when it runs for real.